# "Plädieren auf" versus "plädieren für"

Tags: difference, word-choice, preposition

> - Ich *plädiere für* ein mehrstufiges Wahlverfahren.
> - Der Verteidiger *plädierte auf* Freispruch seines Mandanten.

Gibt es einen Unterschied?

Answer (score 3):

> Gibt es einen Unterschied?

Ja, den gibt es:

*Plädieren **auf*** ist ausschließlich im juristischen Sprachgebrauch im Zusammenhang mit dem [*Plädoyer*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Pl%C3%A4doyer), und dem dabei beantragten [*Strafmaß*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Strafma%C3%9F) üblich.

Die allgemein verbreitete Form ist *plädieren **(da)für***, wobei man dies jedoch auch in juristischem Zusammenhang verwenden kann:

> > Der Staatsanwalt plädierte dafür, den Zeugen nochmals vorzuladen.